# How do I remove specific characters from specific rows in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, contains

I have this column in my table...

1. ***10+ years in business · Bypass Rd, behind ST. Conrad's College***
2. ***5+ years in business  · Ground Floor, 84***
3. ***1st Floor SK Complex, Madison square Rd***
4. ***near C.O. County Office, near Church***
5. ***7+ years in business · David Rd***
6. ***80A, Henry Palace, Phase 1, Ronda Rd***

If you notice there are certain rows which are starting with 7+ years in business or 5+ years in business **WITH ADDRESS**....on the other hand there are some rows which are starting with **ONLY ADDRESS** like

*1st Floor SK Complex, Madison square Rd*

*near C.O. County Office, near Church*

What I want is that how to remove **n+ years of experience** from starting of cell and get rest

like in case of first cell I should get ***ONLY***

**Bypass Rd, behind ST. Conrad's College**

not 10+ years of experience.

Although I am able to do the first one in Pandas but I can't save the remaining one.
like ***1st Floor SK Complex, Madison square Rd*** should not be changed at all.

Comment: How did you do the first one? Please share your code.

Comment: With data cleaning you need to find some sort of pattern (or patterns even). What I can see here are is there is a '·' in between the address and the bit you want to remove. If you did something like df['address'] = df['the column with your data'].str.split('·').str[1] you should be able to get the part that you want.

Comment: @rayad You should post that as an answer. Looks like a good approach.

Answer (score 1):

With data cleaning you need to find some sort of pattern (or patterns even). What I can see here are is there is a `'·'` in between the address and the bit you want to remove. If you did something like `df['address'] = df['the column with your data'].str.split('·').str[1]` you should be able to get the part that you want.